# how to move a program's window with ahk script?

Tags: automation, autohotkey, ui-automation

I'm trying to move a program's window to 0,0 location so this is my code:

```
Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\ThunderSoft\DRM Protection\CPMaker.exe
WinMove, ahk_exe CPMaker.exe, , 0, 0
```

and this is Window Spy's information:

[image: Window Spy]

the first line of the code works but the moving part doesn't. I tried it with `ahk_class TfrmMain` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by adding this line:

```
WinWait, ahk_exe CPMaker.exe, , 5
```

this line waits for the program to start the first parameter is WinTitle and the last one is the timeout in seconds.

the code still didn't work because of permission issues so I had to run it as admin, now it's working.